# Modals in loop display always only the first image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I made a loop for displaying buttons as thumbnail images in users' posts. After clicking such button with miniature a Bootstrap(4.0) modal displays the full image.

The problem is, while the thumbnails on buttons load properly in every post, they all open a modal with the same full image, always the first from the list.
What is the problem?

Here is my view:

```
 @model Dictionary<MyPigeons.Models.Entities.Post, List<MyPigeons.Models.Entities.PostImageGallery>>

<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-muted">@item.Key.UserProfile.FirstName @item.Key.UserProfile.LastName</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-3 text-muted">@item.Key.PostDate</h6>
                <p class="card-text">@item.Key.Content</p>

                @foreach (var itm in item.Value)
                {
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal@itm.PostImageGalleryId">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-rounded" src="~/images/PostImages/@itm.ThumbnailName" alt="Card image">
                    </button>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal@itm.PostImageGalleryId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="~/images/PostImages/@itm.ImageName" alt="Card image">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

the item.Value in foreach is of class PostImageGallery, which is as follows:

```
public class PostImageGallery
{
    [Key]
    public string PostImageGalleryId { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailName { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdditionTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostForeignKey")]
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to make the modal id unique by inserting the @itm.PostImageGalleryId in it but I don't know why the browser sees it as plain text and doesn't exchange the proper value for it. Bellow is the screen from browser's code exploration.

[image]

What is also interesting, on the attached screen, the paths to the thumbnail in the button and to the image in modal rendered correctly, but in fact what diplays in the modal after clicking the button is completely different image with completely different name than this showing while exploring the code in the browser as attached.

Is this a Bootstrap bug? Any ideas how to bypass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bootstrap, you are assigning the unique id with wrong razor syntax. In general in razor, when you write c# code with string, that code is treated like string. A simple solution is wrap that c# code in a `@(<your-c#-code>)`. So, you need to assign the unique id like this:

```
... data-target="#Modal@(itm.PostImageGalleryId)" ...
```

and

```
... id="Modal@(itm.PostImageGalleryId)"...
```